# how to play the audio after given period of time

Tags: objective-c, iphone

i want to play the audio file after the given period of time set by user.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an NSTimer for this purpose like Andy Suggests but it may just over complicate things in this particular situation.  More simply, you could implement something like this:

```
- (void)playSound {
  [sound play];
}

- (void)someMethod {
  float delay = 2.0; // seconds
  [self performSelector:@selector(playSound) withObject:nil afterDelay:delay];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using the [NSTimer](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) class?

Comment: can u give me some code by which i can start some action by using nstimer class